# Правила создания JavaBeans в Spring?

Tags: spring, bean

Почему многие разработчики создают Java Bean в Spring не по правилам? По правилам кроме методов get() и set() нужно переопределить equals, hashcode, toString и имплементировать от интерфейса Serializable. Разве можно использовать только get() и set()?